# Ionic2 Leaflet remains blank on device / simulator

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, leaflet, ionic2

I essentially copied [this](https://github.com/thomashrabe/Ionic2Leaflet) example to display LeafletJS maps with Ionic2. It works fine with ionic serve, but when I run on the device / simulator I keep getting a blank view.

I did not modify anything from the example. May it be some files are missing? One additional major hurdle is the fact that debugging TS files is extremely tedious.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the map was blank is that I had to wrap the map object into a div that derived the size from the ion-content.
Without the encapsulating div and with map on 100% only it wouldn't show properly on the device.

```
<ion-content>
  <div style="height: 100%;width:100%;">
    <div style="height: 100%;width:100%;" id="map"></div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```